# Set cookie in Postman with variable

Tags: postman

I'm trying to write some postman tests that require me to set a cookie.  My first request returns a token in a json payload. I've pulled this out and stored it in a variable but I cant seem to inject this into a cookie for further requests.

I get the value for the cookie like:

```
var json = pm.response.json();
pm.globals.set("my-cookie", json.Token);
```

I've tried this in the cookie dialog box:

```
my-cookie={{my-cookie}}; path=/; domain=.myhost.com; Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT;
```

However when it sends the cookie it sends the above without replacing the variable the, i.e. it has {{my-cookie}} rather than the value of the variable.

I cant see anything in the postman API that will enable me to set cookies on a request grammatically.

I did see this, but it only mentions adding them via the dialog

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/interceptor_extension

I also found this, but could find no mention of how to use it.

https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Cookie.html

I'm assuming this is a common requirement and must be missing something obvious. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try using the Headers feature with a key of `Cookie` and a value of `cookieName={{yourVariable}}`

[image]

Comment: I also did the same thing, but postman site says that you cannot overwrite the headers.  I'm not sure though, if you click the "hidden" link under request Headers on the left, it also has its own Cookie with a gray check meaning you cannot edit that.

Comment: WOW i just learnt from you that the Cookie is actually a key in the headers and all cookie's values are just the value of mentioned key. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Postman - how to set cookies in request]

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, in current version there is a special section for setting request cookies on the righthand side of the request window.

Comment: I tried that, but clicking Add Cookie and saving it just does not work, it creates nothing

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just inserting {{token}} also.

I had to click the 'whitelist domain' under 'cookies' to whitelist my domain first. Then re-request the request that populates the token.
This got it working.

Note if the cookie has secure set, your baseurl should also include https://